# AMC Putnam 1986 № B2

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

There was one task on the competition  http://kskedlaya.org/putnam-archive/

I'm not much will change. Is it possible to solve such a system of Diophantine equations?

$$x(x-a)+2yz=y(y-a)+2xz=z(z-a)+2xy$$

$a - $ The specified number for the problem.  I think we should first find a parametrization of the solutions of this system of equations taking $a$ as unknown. And then to find out for which values of solutions are possible?

Comment: Since everything has positive degree (there are no constants), there is the trivial solution $x = y= z = 0$, but also any solution of the form $x = y=  z =$ anything and $a=$ anything else will do.

Comment: @andybenji stop talking trivial.

Comment: @individ, **please** be nice.

Comment: @individ: It is probably worth pointing out that the original version of the problem differs from your formulation, and likely this the crux of your Question: does replacing $a=1$ with a general parameter affect whether there are only finitely many solutions for the triples $(x-y,y-z,z-x)$.

Comment: @СтивенStadnicki I said that the condition better change. First find out how in General, look solutions, and then find out their properties. What is the meaning set type - if not solved the equation?

Answer (score 3):

Since the terms involving $a$ are all homogenous of degree one, and the other terms are all homogenous of degree two, the parameter $a$ can be removed by a simple rescaling: set $x=ax'$, $y=ay'$, $z=az'$ and the equation becomes $ax'(ax'-a)+2ay'az'=$ etc, where we can factor out to get $a^2(x'(x'-1)+y'z')=$ etc.  In other words, $a$ is a 'false parameter'; the equations are no more general for its introduction than they were without it (n.b.: the original problem from the Putnam exam is the case $a=1$), since solutions of one set map directly to solutions of the other.

Comment: No. This is not a solution. We need to obtain directly the solution of system of equations - that is, its parameterization!

Comment: I'm not attempting to solve the original problem (which had $a=1$).  My point is that introducing $a$ gains nothing and you're just as well off solving the original problem than solving the version with $a$.

Comment: Well. He will think. Generally, there are ideas such as systems to solve it?

Answer (score -2):

In General, the problem looks simple. And I don't understand why. This equation can be rewritten in such a system.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x(x-a)+2yz=y(y-a)+2xz\\&z(z-a)+2xy=y(y-a)+2xz\end{aligned}\right.$$

This is equivalent.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&(x-y)(x+y-a)=2z(x-y)\\&(z-y)(z+y-a)=2x(z-y)\end{aligned}\right.$$

This is equivalent.

$$\left\{\begin{aligned}&x+y-a=2z\\&z+y-a=2x\end{aligned}\right.$$

This will mean that:

$$x=z=y-a$$

Or maybe somewhere made a mistake?